# Pyomo-IPOPT: solver falls into local minima, how to avoid that?

Tags: optimization, pyomo, ipopt

I am trying to solve an optimisation problem consisting in finding the global maximum of a high dimensional (10+) monotonic function (as in monotonic in every direction). The constraints are such that they cut the search space with planes.

I have coded the whole thing in `pyomo` and I am using the `ipopt` solver. In most cases, I am confident it converges successfully to the global optimal. But if I play a bit with the constraints I see that it sometimes converges to a local minima.

It looks like a exploration-exploitation trade-off.
I have looked into the options that can be passed to `ipopt` and the list is so long that I cannot understand which parameters to play with to help with the convergence to the global minima.

**edit:**

Two hints of a solution:

- my variables used to be defined with very infinite bounds, e.g. `bounds=(0,None)` to move on the infinite half-line. I have enforced two finite bounds on them.
- I am now using multiple starts with:

  ```
  opt = SolverFactory('multistart')
  results = opt.solve(self.model, solver='ipopt', strategy='midpoint_guess_and_bound')
  ```

So far this has made my happy with the convergence.

Comment: Just a question. How in Pyomo (or numerically otherise) are you checking, whether the solution converges to a local or global optimum ?

Comment: In my specific case I knew the global minimum from solving it with Gurobi, which was very slow compared to IP-OPT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, IPOPT is a local solver. If you really want to find global solutions, you can use a global solver such as Baron, Couenne or Antigone. There is a trade-off: global solvers are slower and may not work for large problems.

Alternatively, you can help local solvers with a good initial point. Be aware that active set methods are often better in this respect than interior point methods. Sometimes multistart algorithms are used to prevent bad local optima: use a bunch of different starting points. Pyomo has some  facilities to do this (see the documentation).

Comment: Thanks for the input. Local solver means that it does not do any exploration?! It will only go down the hill from its starting point?

Comment: Thanks for the suggesting alternative solvers. I tried Couenne but it is too slow for this case, Baron and Antigone seem to require paying licenses. It seems like I am back on using IPOPT. Do you have a working example of it being passed different starting points?!

Comment: See the documentation here on using the multi-start solver features available in Pyomo: https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contributed_packages/multistart.html

Comment: @BethanyNicholson Thank you so much for the suggestion. I have been playing with this multistart. There is cost in terms of computation time but the convergence is finally reliable!