# Can solver status always be inferred from the termination condition?

Tags: pyomo

I would assume that if the termination condition is "optimal", then the solver status must be "ok". The documentation located at https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/working_models.html#accessing-solver-status seems to confirm this by stating that "the value 'optimal' indicates that the solver succeeded." But the example that follows that paragraph checks that the solver status is "ok" AND that the termination condition is "optimal".

So can the termination condition by itself not be trusted? Are there actually cases where the termination condition is "optimal" but the solver status is something like "error"? Does this depend on which solver is being used?

Adding to my confusion, the example that immediately follows that one checks only the termination condition. The example located at http://www.pyomo.org/blog/2015/1/8/accessing-solver is essentially the same as the first one and checks both solver status and termination condition.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand all your questions, or can answer but I can give you an example that I detailed in [Pyomo-IPOPT: solver falls into local minima, how to avoid that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54975188/pyomo-ipopt-solver-falls-into-local-minima-how-to-avoid-that)

Using `IPOPT` as solver, the solver was falling into a local minima while still returning an optimal condition.

This answers

```
So can the termination condition by itself not be trusted?
```

Yes.

and

```
Does this depend on which solver is being used?
```

Probably, as my test case would not happen with a reliable global solver.

```
Are there actually cases where the termination condition is "optimal" but the solver status is something like "error"?
```

I have never seen this happen, seems like it would mean the logic of the termination messages is broken.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but my question is about why the Pyomo documentation checks both the termination condition and the solver status. The case you mention is actually not even a problem with IPOPT; it is a local solver, and a local minimum is locally optimal.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question completely. Here, since SO isn't a site for "read me the docs" questions, I assume that your question is about the technical way of using the librairy, so I believe this will help answer your question without sounding like I repeat what is in the docs.

The way I see it, solver statuses are used in the given examples as a way of avoiding errors. Logically, solver has to have an "ok" status in order to return a termination condition. Even if your solver returns an "infeasible" status, it doesn't mean that the solver encountered an error, far from it! The status will still be "ok", because your solver worked flawlessly up to now, and is ready for another optimization. However, when the status is "error", it means that something much worst happened. Something broke inside the solver or with its interface to Pyomo and this is one way to find it. Chances are that your solver could not even find a termination condition. In this case, the user might want to avoid retrieving a termination condition when the solver could not even give one. This avoids having to raise exceptions and helps to handle such cases. This is a very good practice.

So, you should not rely solely on the solver status, and you should rely only on the termination condition to know that your problem is "optimal" or "maxTimeLimit" and so on. However, you are better testing if the solver can return a termination condition by using the solver status, in case something bad happens with your solver.

Comment: Thanks for the post! You raised an interesting point about getting an error if the solver didn't return a termination condition. But it isn't clear to me that that can happen. There is an 'unknown' solver status, which is apparently used when the solver status is uninitialized. I was just taking a look at https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/master/pyomo/opt/results/solver.py, and it looks like there is a corresponding 'unknown' termination condition that isn't listed in the documentation. The comments in that file also seem to map every termination condition to a specific solver status.